# How do I dump data from an entire database in Rails 3.2.11?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Django, I run the following to dump the entire database to a json file:

```
django-admin.py dumpdata > data.json
```

What's the equivalent of the above in Rails 3.2.11?  I've tried the following commands but they don't work:

```
rake db:data:dump_dir dir="my_dir"
rake db:fixtures:dump
```

The error message for the above is:

```
user:~/blog$ rake db:fixtures:dump
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'db:fixtures:dump'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails has a schema dumping feature (`rake db:schema:dump`), but no built in data dumping feature.

What database are you using? With MySQL, you can just do a `mysqldump`.

**Edit:**

If you wanted to dump JSON data from one model (assuming it wasn't a ton of data), you could do:

`MyModel.all.to_json`

Comment: I'm trying to migrate data from a sqlite3 to postgres.  I was thinking of doing a data dump to json/yaml and load it back to the postgres db.

Comment: I see. How much data are you dealing with? If it's not too much, you could accomplish this in the console by looping over your models and `to_json`-ing their data.

Comment: There's not a lot of data, just from one table.  Can you post sample code on how this is done?

Answer (score 2):

You can try https://github.com/jetthoughts/yaml_db which is a fork of the original yaml_db https://github.com/adamwiggins/yaml_db

Comment: A further fork by zweitag (https://github.com/zweitag/yaml_db) adds some useful features, like getting a dump of the schema and using JSON as a serialization format.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, this screencast is for you: [#342 Migrating to PostgreSQL](http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql). It uses the [taps](https://github.com/ricardochimal/taps) gem.